# How to optimize a PID overflow?

Tags: c, arm, nintendo

I'm doing a PID overflow on my Nintendo 3DS and I thought that maybe exist some way to do it faster.
The Nintendo 3DS has a exploit (a dumb one) that you can overflow the PID to be equal 0 to get "adm rights". Those exploits are common to downgrade the firmware and install a custom one. 3dbrew.org/wiki/Main_Page you can find more info about this. The limit is 0xFFFFFFFF but takes to much time to aciev this adress (so the next one would be the PID = 0).

My code:

```
 u64 titleid=0x0004001000024000; //promo video, US old3ds. your mileage may vary. it's good to experiment as not all title relaunch spamming works well or at all.

u32 procid;  
u32 launch_flags=0;
u32 target=0xFFFFFFFF; 
 for(u32 i=0 ; i<0x80000000 ; i++){
            NS_LaunchTitle(titleid, launch_flags, &procid);  //loop until pid is right up next to the u32 wrap-around.
            printf("%08X\n",(int)procid);
            NS_TerminateProcessTID(titleid);
            if(procid>=target)break;
}
```

Comment: This looks like something related to a very narrow niche. If you want to get help, you better provide more context.

Comment: [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller)

Comment: I am not talking about PID, but about the nintendo stuff

Comment: @Kevin [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier)

Comment: Hehe..This is exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The Nintendo 3DS has a exploit (a dumb one) that you can overflow the PID to be equal 0 to get "adm rights". Those exploits are common to downgrade the firmware and install a custom one. https://www.3dbrew.org/wiki/Main_Page you can find more info about this.

Comment: You should add this (and more) information to the question body.

Comment: @Nos I'm trying to optimize the loop to run faster. Because doing in that way would be need to run the application for, I don't know, 2 weeks maybe...

Comment: You can't optimize it.  The time is taken by `NS_LaunchTitle`; as the people on the [3DS System flaws wiki](https://www.3dbrew.org/wiki/3DS_System_Flaws#ARM11_software) say, it would take weeks if not month to run.

Answer (score 0):

To make the loop execute faster, the quickest win would be to remove the printf statement.

If you really need to monitor progress, why not print out every 100 iterations or so?

eg:

```
if((i%100)==0)
    printf("%08X\n",(int)procid);
```